# Difference between shared memory and pipe in unix?

Tags: unix, terminology

what is main difference between **shared memory** and **pipe** in unix programming?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taken from [this article](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/shared-memory-vs-pipes-for-ipc-602255/)

**(unnamed) Pipes**

- Can switch between blocking and
  non-blocking mode
- Don't have to free them when done
- Are automatically inherited by
  children
- Must read and write in a linear
  fashion

**Shared Memory**

- Can store structures
- Won't ever block - positive
- Can have as many programs read or
  write to it as you need
- Won't ever block - negative: must use
  semaphores or your own spin-locks
- It's possible for it to not be freed
  even when all programs exit

Answer (score 2):

Shared Memory Vs Pipe-

**Kernel-**

Once Shared Memory is setup by the kernel there is no further need of kernel for the communication b/w process whereas in Pipe, data is buffered in the kernel space and requires system call for each access. Here, Shared Memory is faster than Pipe. It is a major drawback of the pipe becuase IPC is important for the computational speed up.

**Communication**

Shared Memory- Bidirectional whereas Pipe(unnamed Pipe)- Unidirectional.

**Reliable**

Shared Memory- Less Reliable(data mix up) whereas Pipe is more Reliable as data is buffered and is under control of the kernel.

Hope you like it.